# C code only prints after ^Z

Tags: c

I'm reading K&R's book on C and i got to this part where the output would be the number of newlines that you input.I wanted to make it so that it prints out each number corresponding to the amount of newlines typed as the lines are being read.This only outputs the value of nl after F6 or CTRL+Z has been pressed(EOF).Could someone explain to me why?

```
int main(){


int c, nl = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    if (c == '\n')
        ++nl;
        printf("%d\n", nl);
}
```

Comment: You forgot braces on your `if`. Also CTRL-D is EOF, CTRL-Z is sleep.

Comment: @kabanus welcome to windows, please deposit your unix badge at the security desk near the main entrance, thank you.

Comment: @n.m. Seriously, different control codes? Thanks for correcting me!

Comment: @kabanus Actually you can make `eof` be CTRL-Z on Unix using `stty`, CTRL-D is the *default*, it is not set in stone.  Changing the control codes on someone's terminal when they left it logged on would be childish :-)  (don't forget to do a `clear` afterwards`).

Comment: @cdarke But funny (really, funny. Trumps the sneaky capslock by a bunch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot some brackets. Here's what your code does currently:

```
int main(){

    int c, nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (c == '\n'){
            ++nl;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", nl);
}
```

Here's what you probably wanted to do based of indentation:

```
int main(){

    int c, nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (c == '\n'){
            ++nl;
            printf("%d\n", nl);
        }
    }
}
```

In C, whitespace is mostly ignored. If you want to run multiple statements together in a block, you need to surround that code with brackets `{}`

Comment: Can you please explain how does c work as an int? From what I know `\n` is a newline character, so shouldn't it be `char c`?

Comment: @parth: `getchar()` returns an `int`, because it needs to be able to return `EOF` (which is not a valid `char` value.) Also, `char` is an integer type.

Comment: @rici that makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Haha that was my bad. The code is running perfectly now thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop ends only when the character is an EOF character. EOF is a special character that represents the end of the file the program is reading. Since you are reading from the console, the console itself is the file you are reading from but it as no end. However in your system you can send an EOF character to the console by typing F6 or CTRL+Z

Instead if you want to print the number of lines while typing you should change your code like this:

```
int main(){
    int c, nl = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (c == '\n'){
            ++nl;
            printf("%d\n", nl);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Newbie error from my part, it runs perfectly now!